# Apache Load Balancer Worker not used anymore after a fail

Tags: apache, load-balancing, failover, worker

I've set up a Load Balancer for Apache 2.2.16 that works ok except for 1 thing: when one of my 2 workers come back to available after being in failure (manual shutdown + wait + restart for instance). The LB sees the unavailability, stops forwarding requests but never sees it coming back to life. Here is my config (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_balancer.conf), I tried using "retry=" option but that doesn't seem to be enough or be the correct way to do:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
   BalancerMember http://192.168.0.11 route=srv1 retry=60
   BalancerMember http://192.168.0.12 route=srv2 retry=60
   ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
```

Any idea, tip, link ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it, it seems to be a bug in Apache 2.2 (up to 2.2.23?), when "bybusiness" method is used with "retry" parameter. Switching to "byrequests" fixed my prob.